# iOS: how to set httponly flag for NSHTTPCookie

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, nshttpcookie

I am using the following code to construct NSHTTPCookie But there is no options to set httpOnly flag for cookie

```
[cookieProperties setObject:@"name" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"value" forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
[cookieProperties setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey:NSHTTPCookieDiscard];
[cookieProperties setObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"isSecure"] forKey:NSHTTPCookieSecure];


[cookieProperties setObject:@"abc.xyz.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"abc.xyz.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieOriginURL];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"/" forKey:NSHTTPCookiePath];
[cookieProperties setObject:@"0" forKey:NSHTTPCookieVersion];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Apple documentation:

> HTTPOnly Property
>
> A boolean value that indicates whether the receiver should only be sent to HTTP servers per RFC 2965. (read-only)
>
> Declaration
>
> > SWIFT
> >
> > > ```
> > > var HTTPOnly: Bool { get }
> > > ```
> > >
> > > OBJECTIVE-C
> > >
> > > ```
> > > @property(readonly, getter=isHTTPOnly) BOOL HTTPOnly
> > > ```
>
> Returns YES if this cookie should only be sent via HTTP headers, NO
>   otherwise.
>
> ***Cookies may be marked as HTTP only by a server (or by a javascript).
>   Cookies marked as such must only be sent via HTTP Headers in HTTP
>   requests for URL's that match both the path and domain of the
>   respective cookies.***

You can only set the HTTPOnly flag from the server or through a javascript. This isn't possible through the native iOS application code.

Comment: How to add a boolean value to NSHTTPCookieValue instead of string?

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct, there's an undocumented property which allows creating httpOnly cookies.

Answer (score 14):

There's an [undocumented cookie property key](https://blink.lc/chromium/tree/ios/net/cookies/system_cookie_util.mm?id=d72441d795c9e7a397c96ddbb79409e22fc73ea3#n33) (found through [@mikewest](https://twitter.com/mikewest/status/693046871347052544)):

> // Undocumented property of NSHTTPCookie.
>   NSString* const kNSHTTPCookieHttpOnly = @"HttpOnly";

I tried it in Swift, and it the code does what it's expected to do.

```
import Foundation

extension HTTPCookiePropertyKey {
    static let httpOnly = HTTPCookiePropertyKey("HttpOnly")
}

let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
  .domain: "example.org",
  .path: "/",
  .name: "Cookie Example",
  .value: "Om nom nom",

  .version: 1, // RFC2965 for HttpOnly cookies
  .httpOnly: true
])!

print(cookie.isHTTPOnly) // true
```

Comment: does this really work? I do see the true statement in my logs.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine for me and it's really weird from WK API that this property is not exposed. Thank you for this answer 

Comment: Works great, verified by inspecting the page with Safari developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone stumbling across this:

```
let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
.domain: "xxxx.xxxx",
.path: "/",
.name: "token",
.value: "xxxxxx",
.version: 1,
.secure: true,
.expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1234),
.init(rawValue: "HttpOnly"): true
```

])!

```
print(cookie.isHTTPOnly) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSHTTPCookiePropertyKey` is just a typedef used for a set of string constants. String literals can be used for any standard cookie attribute that doesn't have a corresponding NSHTTPCookiePropertyKey.

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:@{
    NSHTTPCookieName : @"name",
    NSHTTPCookiePath : @"/",
    NSHTTPCookieValue : @"value",
    NSHTTPCookieDomain : @".example.com",
    @"HttpOnly" : @YES
}];
```